# cascade this query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, truncate, cascade

I want to cascade this query.

```
SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' ||  tablename || ';' FROM pg_tables WHERE tableowner='XXX';
```

I want all the tables by owner "xxx" to be truncated (this works) but I want it also cascade. How can I make it cascade?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' ||  tablename || ' CASCADE;' FROM pg_tables WHERE tableowner='XXX';`?

Answer (score 1):

Add the [keyword `CASCADE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html) like [@clemens commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960423/cascade-this-query#comment82890380_47960423).
But also escape `tablename` to avoid SQL injection and other errors. Most elegantly with [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

```
SELECT format('TRUNCATE TABLE %I CASCADE;', tablename)
FROM   pg_tables WHERE tableowner = 'XXX';
```